# iMessage stuck in Notification Center

Tags: macos, messages, ui

I have this weird situation where I was using the reply-from-Notification-Center Messages feature and it got stuck in the write-the-message state, as in the screenshot below.

[image]

The message was sent, but ever since it got stuck and it’s unusable.

How can I reset it without restarting the computer or logging out?

(I’m on Mavericks.)

Comment: Can you open console, reproduce problem and save the output to pastebin.com?

Comment: have you tried to force quit?

Comment: @Gabkano force quit what? Notification Center? Is it possible?

Comment: @TheBro21 No, I can’t reproduce the problem, since is stuck in that state, so I can’t write any new messages from the interface.

Comment: force quit iMesage

Comment: @Gabkano Messages works flawlessly. It opens and it closes without problems.

Comment: after you completely closed iMessage with the option "close iMessage" found in the option-bar called "iMessage" in the top of the screen, the notification still doesn't disappear?   Why can't you restart or log out which would be the best and fastest solution?

Comment: @Gabkano Yes, exactly, after quitting Messages, the notification still doesn’t disappear. I was able to fix it by killing Notification Center (see my own answer to the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by killing Notification Center with the following command:

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

You could also force-quit it from Activity Monitor.

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/18/how-to-restart-notification-center-in-os-x/).